# Using Try and Catch for Exception in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

Can anyone teach me where to insert **try/catch** into this code for making sure it won't crash if user enters a string that isn’t “**Quit**” or also isn’t a number? The following code is used for calculating the average of some numbers. My professor didn't tell us which **exception** we shall use. Also I am not quite familiar with them.

```
import io.StdIn._

def sumAndCount() : (Int, Int) = {
    println("Please enter a number; or enter Quit:")
    val input = readLine.toLowerCase.trim
    input match {
        case "quit" => (0, 0)
        case _ => val (sum, count) =  sumAndCount()
                  (input.toInt+sum, count + 1)
    }
}

val (sum, count) = sumAndCount()
val aver = sum.toDouble/count

println(f"The average is $aver")
```

Comment: Hint: with your current code, what happens when something that is neither "Quit" nor a number is entered? (Have you tried it?)

Comment: when you call `toInt` on a string you can get `NumberFormatException`. I believe you should redesign this code, it doesn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io.StdIn._

def sumAndCount(sum: Int, count: Int) : (Int, Int) = {
    println("Please enter a number; or enter Quit:")
    val input = readLine.toLowerCase.trim
    input match {
        case "quit" => (sum, count)
        case _ => try {
          val number = input.toInt
          sumAndCount(sum + number, count + 1)
        } catch {
          case _: NumberFormatException =>
            println("that's not a number, try again")
            sumAndCount(sum, count)
        }
    }
}

val (sum, count) = sumAndCount(0, 0)
val aver = sum.toDouble / count

println(f"The average is $aver")
```

You may also want to handle the case when user types only quit, atm result will be `NaN`.

Please take look at problems with your code. You want to call this function recursive like this, not like you did it.